# Python Compare List to Dict Value

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

**Updated in an attempt to be more clear**

I have three list of dictionaries that I want to merge into one based on a value.

The lists looks like this.  They vary in how many dictionaries that they can have.

```
unplanned = [{'service__name': u'Email', 'service_sum': 4}, {'service__name': u'Peoplesoft', 'service_sum': 2}]
planned = [{'service__name': u'Email', 'service_sum': 2}, {'service__name': u'Gopher', 'service_sum': 2}, {'service__name': u'Peoplesoft', 'service_sum': 4}]
emerg = [{'service__name': u'Internet', 'service_sum': 1}]
```

I want to take the 3 lists and and create a new list that has the name's from all 3 lists and the values or 0 in a set order.  So I am thinking something like this.

```
[(Email, (4, 2, 0)), (Peoplesoft, (2, 4, 0)), Gopher, (0, 2, 0)), Internet, (0, 0, 1))]
```

I thought I should create a list of the service__name's to compare against each list so I did that but I am not sure how to compare the 3 lists against this name list.  I thought izip_longest would work but have no idea how to implement it.  I am using 2.7.

Comment: What else is in these lists?  Are we supposed to assume that `unplanned[0]` is the only element in `unplanned` that is important?  (and that you only care about `Email`, not `Network`?)

Comment: There is about 100 different services that could be in any of the lists.   I want every service listed that is in the returned lists.  The lists are generated by Django Query.   I was just showing it as an example.  So in unplanned there could 10 services listed, planned 18 and emerg 0.

Comment: I don't understand the intended relationship between input and output. Could you be a little more explicit/precise with the example? (Show a few more list contents, make sure everything matches up exactly, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following codes. You can give variables better name since you know better about the contexts.

```
def convert(unplanned, planned, emerg):
    chain = (unplanned, planned, emerg)
    names = map(lambda lst: [d['service__name'] for d in lst], chain)
    sums = map(lambda lst: [d['service_sum'] for d in lst], chain)
    ds = [dict(zip(n, s)) for n,s in zip(names, sums)]
    unique_names = set([])
    unique_names = reduce(unique_names.union,names)
    results = []
    for n in unique_names:
        s = []
        for i in range(3):
            s.append(ds[i].get(n,0))
        results.append((n, tuple(s)))

    return results

print convert(unplanned, planned, emerg)
```

The output at my machine is

```
[(u'Internet', (0, 0, 1)), (u'Peoplesoft', (2, 4, 0)), (u'Email', (4, 2, 0)), (u'Gopher', (0, 2, 0))]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..  It returns the data correctly but it iterates 3 times so the data is coming back.  [(u'Interent', (0,)), (u'Interent', (0,0)), (u'Interent', (0,0,1)),

Comment: Watch for the indent in the codes you copied. I guess there was an indent error when you copied the codes.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a dict, then convert it into a list afterwards:

```
some_list = [{'service__name': u'Email', 'service_sum': 4}, {'service__name': u'Email', 'service_sum': 1}, {'service__name': u'Network', 'service_sum': 0}]

def combine(list):
   combined = {}
   for item in list:
      if item['service__name'] not in combined:
         combined[item['service__name']] = []
      combined[item['service__name']].append(item['service_sum'])
   return combined.items()

combine(some_list)  # [(u'Email', [4, 1]), (u'Network', [0])]
combine(unplanned)
combine(emerg + planned)
.....
```

Here's the version of the function that uses defaultdict:

```
def combine(list):
   from collections import defaultdict
   combined = defaultdict(list)
   for item in list:
      combined[item['service__name']].append(item['service_sum'])
   return combined.items()
```

A little cleaner, but there's an unnecessary import, and a few other problems with it that may pop up in the future if the function definition is changed (see comments).

Comment: If you wanna get really fancy, the if statement can be removed if `combined = defaultdict(list)`.  I just don't like them, as it has a tendency to clutter up the keys.

Comment: I think a defaultdict is much nicer here -- and it avoids doing the key lookup twice.

Comment: The problem with this one is that it results in `'Email',[4,1]` instead of `'Email',(4,0,1)`.  Of course, that is reasonably easily fixed ...

Comment: @mgilson You did say to group them by `service__name`, rather than by the list itself.  ('Tho if you're referring to the list instead of a tuple, I suggest not changing it to a tuple; those are best used when positions matter, such as (x, y) coordinates, and so on)

Comment: Comment referenced in the answer:  During a large refactoring of our code at work, I learned that we apparently _loved_ checking to see if a key was in a defaultdict by using `if ddict[key]`.  _Never do that_, because even though there's no assignment going on, it _does_ populate the defaultdict with an empty list, which was causing several very strange and hard to hit bugs all over the project.  Using a plain dict will force everyone to use the correct `if key in <dict>` form.

Comment: This isn't a problem with `defaultdict`.  This is a problem with how you're using it.  If you use the defaultdict just like you would use any dictionary, you don't run into that problem.  (check if it has the key by `if key in ddict`).  Of course, you can run into problems in situations where you `try` and then catch a `KeyError` if the key isn't there, but the entire purpose of a default dict is to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you could do something like:

```
output = []
for dicts in zip(unplanned,planned,emerg):
    output.append(('Email',tuple(d['service_sum'] if d['service__name'] == 'Email' else 0 for d in dicts)))
```

Comment: The order isn't guaranteed so you could zip the wrong thing together.

Comment: @AliAfshar -- I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment.  The order of what isn't guaranteed?  `unplanned`, `planned`, etc. are all lists, so their order *is guaranteed*.